# python tkinter treeview set focus to newly inserted item

Tags: python, tkinter, focus

I am inserting a new item with eg:

```
# Insert new item as child of current item
tree.insert(current_node_iid, 1, text="New note")
```

And I can set focus on an item with:

```
# Must select and then focus using the iid of an item
tree.selection_set("I001")
tree.focus("I001")
```

BUT if I insert a new item, and I let Python set the index of the new item, then I do not know this new index, and so I cannot set focus on the new item.

I could of course specify the iid of the new item, but then I would have to check if the iid has already been used by another item, which I dont know how to do.

How do I set focus on a new item?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define a variable for your `tree.insert` command.

```
a = tree.insert(current_node_iid, 1, text="New note")
print (a)
```

Result:

```
I001
```

Comment: Thank you again for your help again Henry :)
I will give that a try.....

Comment: Works great! Thanks again.

Comment: I thought I could select your answer as THE answer to my question but it seems I am not able to do so :(